# Javascript - Make specific text a link

Tags: javascript, regex, function

I'm looking at a 'to do' list application that uses JavaScript.
One of the functions converts text in to a hyperlink when https, https or ftp is present.

I'd like to expand this so if my text contains # followed by any 5 digit number, that becomes a link as well. The URL should be  `http://192.168.0.1/localsite/testschool/search.php?id=ID`

where ID is the # and 5 digit number.

This is the current Javascript:

```
function prepareHtml(s)
{
    // make URLs clickable
    s = s.replace(/(^|\s|>)(www\.([\w\#$%&~\/.\-\+;:=,\?\[\]@]+?))(,|\.|:|)?(?=\s|&quot;|&lt;|&gt;|\"|<|>|$)/gi, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>$4');
    return s.replace(/(^|\s|>)((?:http|https|ftp):\/\/([\w\#$%&~\/.\-\+;:=,\?\[\]@]+?))(,|\.|:|)?(?=\s|&quot;|&lt;|&gt;|\"|<|>|$)/ig, '$1<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>$4');
};
```

called using `prepareHtml(item.title)`

Any idea how I can do this ?
I've worked out regex to match the # and 5 digits is `^#([0-9]{5})` but I'm not sure how to implement this in the function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me that the pattern & replace string can be simplified a bit.

```js
function urls2links(s)
{
    
return s.replace(/(^|[\s>])(www\.)/gi, '$1http://$2')
        .replace(/\b(((https?|ftps?):\/{2})(\S+?))(?=&quot;|&lt;|&gt;|[\s<>\"]|$)/ig, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
};

var str = 'blah http://192.168.0.1/localsite/testschool/search.php?id=#12345 \nblah www.foo.com/bar/&quot; blah';

console.log('--\n-- BEFORE\n--');
console.log(str);
console.log('--\n-- AFTER\n--');
console.log(urls2links(str));
```

Although I'm not too sure about needing to include the character entities `|&quot;|&lt;|&gt;` in the lookahead.
But I'm guessing you also deal with encoded strings.

Comment: thanks this helps :)

Comment: @Rocket, Thx. The new version has extra to add the http protocol before a `www.` without a protocol.